# Run Gatsy develop with access to REST API not possible

Tags: azure-sql-database, fetch-api, gatsby, azure-static-web-app

I want to create an Gatsby App with calling REST API of my Azure SQL Database to read data.
In my deployed Azure Static Web App (SWA) the access works fine, in "Gatsby develop" mode not.

Here is my GET-request:
`fetch('https://example.com/data-api/rest/blogs')`

I receive the following error message with gatsy develop:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://example.com/data-api/rest/blogs' from origin 'http://localhost:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Also adding the "no-cors" mode to my GET-request did not help.
   `fetch('https://example.com/data-api/rest/blogs/', { method: 'GET', mode: "no-cors", headers: {  "Content-Type": "application/json" }`

Comment: please share the code and link you followed

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Make sure to cors on api side

Answer (score 0):

The error you are encountering is due to a CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) issue when trying to access your Azure SQL Database REST API from your local Gatsby development environment. Make sure to add CORS.

I created a simple Gatsby app using the command:
`npx gatsby new static-web-app`

To add CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing), use the `cors` middleware:
`npm install cors`

**`package.json`:**

```json
"dependencies": {
    "gatsby": "^5.13.3",
    "gatsby-plugin-image": "^3.13.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^5.13.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^5.13.1",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^5.13.1",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^5.13.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "engines":{
    "node":">=18.0.0"
  },
```

**staticwebapp.config.json:**

```
{
    "navigationFallback": {
      "rewrite": "index.html"
    }
}
```

[image]

**Azure:**
[image]
**Azure Sql:**
[image]

```js
app.use(cors()); // Use the cors middleware

// Server and database configuration
const config = {
    server: process.env.AZURE_SQL_SERVER,
    port: process.env.AZURE_SQL_PORT,
    database:  process.env.AZURE_SQL_DATABASE,
    user: process.env.AZURE_SQL_USER,
    password: process.env.AZURE_SQL_PASSWORD,
    options: {
        encrypt: true,
        trustServerCertificate: false,
        connectionTimeout: 30000,
        requestTimeout: 30000 // optional request timeout in milliseconds
    }
};

// Endpoint to fetch persons
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const pool = await sql.connect(config);
        const result = await pool.request().query('select * from [dbo].[employees]');
        res.status(200).json(result.recordset);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error reading data from database:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
    }
});
```

**Azure:**

[image]